# How to have bold font in mdframed environment?

Tags: formatting, bold, mdframed

I did not find bold word in the [manual](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex2e/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf).
My tex is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
Lorem. % No bolding needed here so save space here, but need to fix the above
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

How can you have bold font in mdframed environment?

Comment: So you want `Lorem` to be bold?

Comment: If you want the whole environment body bold adding the option `font=\bfseries` to the style definition should do

Comment: @cgnieder: Sounds like the answer.

Comment: And perhaps you want to take a look at the `\newmdtheoremenv` command as described in Section 8 of the »[mdframed](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed)« manual.

Comment: So you searched for "bold" in the manual, which returned no hits, and you instantly gave up? That's not reasonable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a kind of title for your questions and that title should be bold-faced, In this case, you can define a new theorem style and use the note field (the optional argument) to get the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}%
  {\topsep}%
  {\itshape}%
  {}%
  {\bfseries}%
  {.}%
  {.5em}%
  {\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{. \bfseries#3}}%
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}[Lorem]
Text
\end{question}
\begin{question}
Text
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, on the other side you want all the contents bold-faced, you have two options:

1. If you are not using `amsthm`, simply add `font=\bfseries` to the `mdframed` specifications:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

   \newtheorem{question}{Question}
   \mdfdefinestyle{que}{
     linecolor=cyan,
     font=\bfseries,
     backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
   }
   \surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{question}
   Text
   \end{question}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. If you are using `amsthm`, you'll need to add the specification to the theorem style:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsthm}
   \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

   \newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
     {\topsep}%
     {\topsep}%
     {\bfseries\itshape}%
     {}%
     {\bfseries}%
     {.}%
     {.5em}%
     {}%
   \theoremstyle{mystyle}
   \newtheorem{question}{Question}
   \mdfdefinestyle{que}{
     linecolor=cyan,
     backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
   }
   \surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{question}
   Text
   \end{question}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Notice that italics plus bold-face might not be the best choice.

Comment: Very thorough answer again - thank you!