# To label Question environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, mdframed

My minimum code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=green!40,
    frametitlerule=true
}
\newenvironment{question}[1]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=ans,frametitle={Question: #1}]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\label{masi} % PROBLEM here, since label not working!
{Question body here? What is your question?}
Answer is this and this. Lorem yea.   
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

which has developed from [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162000/how-to-have-bold-font-in-mdframed-environment) but where label does not work.

**How can you use label in a such environment?**

Comment: `\label` needs a counter, since it uses the last counter value to be fed to `\refstepcounter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be a counter for the `\label` command, I introduced a new counter called  `question`. Ideally, the counter should be printed on the question too, I have added this by now and the reference works too.

`\label` uses the the value of the last counter, that was incremented by `\refstepcounter`. If there many sections in your code, it is probably convenient to use `\newcounter{question}[section]` in order to reset it and perhaps redefine `\thequestion` command to

```
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{question}
```

As there are no sections, I have omitted that redefine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=green!40,
    frametitlerule=true
}

\newcounter{question}[section]%
\setcounter{question}{0}

\newenvironment{question}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{question}%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=ans,frametitle={Question \thequestion: #1}]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
 % PROBLEM here, since label not working!
{Question body here? What is your question?}
\label{masi}
Answer is this and this. Lorem yea.   
\end{question}

\begin{question}
 % PROBLEM here, since label not working!
{Question body here? What is your question?}
\label{masi2}
Answer is this also. Lorem yea.   
\end{question}


The Question \ref{masi} was really tricky, but Question \ref{masi2} was really tricky ;-)




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: on could avoid defining new counters and all the stuff if the `question` environment were a `\newmdtheoremenv`.

Answer (score 4):

May be you can consider `tcolorbox`. It offers a `theorems` library which simplifies definition and use of enumerated colorfull boxes.

The macro

```
\newtcbtheorem[<init options>]{<name>}{<display name>}{<options>}{<prefix>}
```

defines a new `name` enumerated environment (no worry about counters the package take care of them). `display name` will appear before number, `options` define environment style and `prefix` will be internally added as prefix to all used labels. After definition, in your text you can use

```
\begin{name}{Some description text}{label}
....
\end{name}
```

This create a boxed environment with `Some description text` in title box, `...` in lower box and with `prefix:label` as label for further reference. Here you have a little example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    questionstyle/.style={enhanced, colback=white, colframe=blue!20, arc=0pt, 
                                 fonttitle=\bfseries, colbacktitle=green!40,coltitle=black, 
                                 boxed title style={arc=0pt}}
    }

\newtcbtheorem[]{myquestion}{Question}{questionstyle}{quest}

\begin{document}

\begin{myquestion}{Question Body goes here. As you can see this is a very long question. At least its title is. What's your question?}{masi}
This is my answer
\end{myquestion}

\begin{myquestion}{New question related to question \ref{quest:masi}}{masi2}
This is the answer to question \ref{quest:masi2} which was related with question \ref{quest:masi}
\end{myquestion}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I considered to propose that too -- in fact, my (yet-not-ready-to-be-published) package uses `tcolorbox` environments for question-solution behaviour.

Comment: I want to use the tag *label* in the environment.

Comment: @Masi Sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Masi: The label is contained in the 2nd argument, which is basically the same as writing it yourself within the environment body, apart from being shorter `;-)`