# To make Question environment Discussion environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

About minimal thing developed originally mostly by *Gonzalo Medina* in earlier discussions of mine (one of them [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162004/13173))

```
\documentclass{article}        
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=green!40,
    frametitlerule=true
}
\newcounter{question}[section]%
\setcounter{question}{0}

\newenvironment{question}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{question}%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=ans,frametitle={Question: #1}]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%

}%
\begin{document}


\begin{question}
{Main complaints of this patient with hepatitis?}
Muscle pain.
Jaundice is a typical symptom (nonspecific) but not pain. 
% Icterus is not a complain
Enlargement of the liver.  % hepatomegaly
\textbf{Why muscle pain is coming?} 
Virus infection. 
% There exists no specific symptom for viral hepatitis. 
Intoxication can be but it is untypical.
\textbf{What can you find in the blood analysis?} 
Increased liver enzymes (ALAT, ASAT). 
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

It looks like

[image]

which I would like to change to look more like a discussion: same bolding to questions and green decoration etc, put on left hand side; 
simple text for answers, put on right-hand-side.
I am open to any other suggestions for improvements.

**My pseudocode**

```
\begin{question}
{Main complaints of this patient with hepatitis?}
Muscle pain.
Jaundice is a typical symptom (nonspecific) but not pain. 
% Icterus is not a complain
Enlargement of the liver.  % hepatomegaly
{Why muscle pain is coming?} 
Virus infection. 
% There exists no specific symptom for viral hepatitis. 
Intoxication can be but it is untypical.
{What can you find in the blood analysis?} 
Increased liver enzymes (ALAT, ASAT). 
\end{question}
```

which includes now three questions in one environment. 
**NB** there is no `textbf` here anymore - only three questions!
I am not sure how flexible this `mdframed` is to change to this.

The environment can be surrounded by any way, you want. 
The questions should be clearly visualised at the left hand hand side for instance. 
Their answers next to them. 
I would like to give the subquestions the same value as the first questions. 
At the moment, there is a hierarchy.

**How can you make the mdframed environment more flexible with many questions?**

Comment: `which I would like to change to look more like a discussion` -- What does this mean?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added my explanation to the body. Give same decoration to questions marked by braces "{...}". Put their answers to the right-hand side of the questions. I am open to other suggestions for improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I have defined the `Question` environment which uses a `minipage` for each comoponent and then the question and answer are placed in their own `mdframed` boxes:

[image]

If you want something like the iOS bubbles you can use the `QuestionIOS` environment defined below:

[image]

---

When you have a series of questions they should be specified in their own `QuestionIOS` environment:

```
\begin{QuestionIOS}{Main complaints of this patient with hepatitis?}
    Muscle pain.
    Jaundice is a typical symptom (nonspecific) but not pain. 
    % Icterus is not a complain
    Enlargement of the liver.  % hepatomegaly
\end{QuestionIOS}
\begin{QuestionIOS}{Why muscle pain is coming?} 
    Virus infection. 
    % There exists no specific symptom for viral hepatitis. 
    Intoxication can be but it is untypical.
\end{QuestionIOS}
\begin{QuestionIOS}{What can you find in the blood analysis?} 
    Increased liver enzymes (ALAT, ASAT). 
\end{QuestionIOS}
```

which yields:

[image]

An alternate is `QuestionIOSAlt` environment within which you can use `\newQuestionAlt` to define a new question which is closer to your `pseudocode`. This yields results identical to what is shown above.

```
\begin{QuestionIOSAlt}{Main complaints of this patient with hepatitis?}
        Muscle pain.
        Jaundice is a typical symptom (nonspecific) but not pain. 
        % Icterus is not a complain
        Enlargement of the liver.  % hepatomegaly
    \newQuestionAlt{Why muscle pain is coming?} 
        Virus infection. 
        % There exists no specific symptom for viral hepatitis. 
        Intoxication can be but it is untypical.
    \newQuestionAlt{What can you find in the blood analysis?} 
        Increased liver enzymes (ALAT, ASAT). 
\end{QuestionIOSAlt}
```

### Note:

- No changes are required to how you specify the info. Just using a different environment changes the style of the output.
- If you don't want the questions in bold, remove the `\bfseries` in the environment definitions.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}        
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
}
\mdfdefinestyle{ques}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=green!20,
}

\newcounter{question}[section]%
\setcounter{question}{0}

\newenvironment{question}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{question}%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=ans,frametitle={Question: #1}]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%

}%

\newenvironment{Question}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{question}%
    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}{0.22\linewidth}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=ques]
            \bfseries\raggedright
            Question: #1
        \end{mdframed}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.70\linewidth}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=ans]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
    \end{minipage}%
}%

\newenvironment{QuestionIOS}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{question}%
    \smallskip\par%
    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=ques, roundcorner=7.0pt, linewidth=1pt]
            \bfseries\raggedright
            Question: #1
        \end{mdframed}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \smallskip\par\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=ans, roundcorner=7.0pt, linewidth=1pt]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
    \end{minipage}%
}%

\newenvironment{QuestionIOSAlt}[1]{%
    \newcommand*{\newQuestionAlt}[1]{%
            \end{mdframed}%
            \end{minipage}%
            \refstepcounter{question}%
            \smallskip\par%
            \noindent%
            \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
            \begin{mdframed}[style=ques, roundcorner=7.0pt, linewidth=1pt]
                \bfseries\raggedright
                Question: ##1
            \end{mdframed}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \smallskip\par\hfill%
        \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=ans, roundcorner=7.0pt, linewidth=1pt]
    }%
    \refstepcounter{question}%
    \smallskip\par%
    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=ques, roundcorner=7.0pt, linewidth=1pt]
            \bfseries\raggedright
            Question: #1
        \end{mdframed}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \smallskip\par\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=ans, roundcorner=7.0pt, linewidth=1pt]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
    \end{minipage}%
}%


\newcommand*{\AnswerText}{%
Muscle pain.
Jaundice is a typical symptom (nonspecific) but not pain. 
% Icterus is not a complain
Enlargement of the liver.  % hepatomegaly
\textbf{Why muscle pain is coming?} 
Virus infection. 
% There exists no specific symptom for viral hepatitis. 
Intoxication can be but it is untypical.
\textbf{What can you find in the blood analysis?} 
Increased liver enzymes (ALAT, ASAT). 
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\verb|question| environment:\medskip\par
\begin{question}{Main complaints of this patient with hepatitis?}
\AnswerText
\end{question}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
\noindent\verb|Question| environment:\medskip\par
\begin{Question}{Main complaints of this patient with hepatitis?}
\AnswerText
\end{Question}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
\noindent\verb|QuestionIOS| environment:\medskip\par
\begin{QuestionIOS}{Main complaints of this patient with hepatitis?}
\AnswerText
\end{QuestionIOS}

\clearpage
\noindent\verb|QuestionIOS| environment with multiple questions:\medskip\par
\begin{QuestionIOS}{Main complaints of this patient with hepatitis?}
    Muscle pain.
    Jaundice is a typical symptom (nonspecific) but not pain. 
    % Icterus is not a complain
    Enlargement of the liver.  % hepatomegaly
\end{QuestionIOS}
\begin{QuestionIOS}{Why muscle pain is coming?} 
    Virus infection. 
    % There exists no specific symptom for viral hepatitis. 
    Intoxication can be but it is untypical.
\end{QuestionIOS}
\begin{QuestionIOS}{What can you find in the blood analysis?} 
    Increased liver enzymes (ALAT, ASAT). 
\end{QuestionIOS}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
\noindent\verb|QuestionIOSAlt| environment with multiple questions and \verb|\newQuestionAlt| to start a new question:\medskip\par
\begin{QuestionIOSAlt}{Main complaints of this patient with hepatitis?}
        Muscle pain.
        Jaundice is a typical symptom (nonspecific) but not pain. 
        % Icterus is not a complain
        Enlargement of the liver.  % hepatomegaly
    \newQuestionAlt{Why muscle pain is coming?} 
        Virus infection. 
        % There exists no specific symptom for viral hepatitis. 
        Intoxication can be but it is untypical.
    \newQuestionAlt{What can you find in the blood analysis?} 
        Increased liver enzymes (ALAT, ASAT). 
\end{QuestionIOSAlt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This good alternative! What about this: put all questions to the left and their corresponding answers to right - like iOS message system with bubles.

Comment: @Masi: See updated answer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: It is good and almost. I mean to have those two other questions also at the left-hand-side as green bubbles, while their answers at the right-hand-side. Note that there is no **textbf** in my pseudocode. So questions are marked by braces **{..}** anywhere in the environment.

Comment: @Masi: Perhaps I am not fully understanding your question. If you have more than one question, _each_ one gets its own environment. You proposed usage as shown in the `pseudocode` in the question is not the LaTeX way. It can probably be done, but I would _not_ recommend that approach. It is much easier if you do it as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for alternative! I am worried about the link going to be lost between those three questions. I have many questions in my body. My pseudocode way would be very easy to hold the record. Probably, there exists some parameters which you can use inside the environment to have a similar result.

Comment: You still need someway to mark a new question. I have again revised the answer -- this time there is the `` environment within which you can mark the start of a new question with ``. Hopefully this addresses your question. Otherwise, please edit the question and clarify further.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and updates! I really like the last edit. It is exactly what I was looking for.