# How to bold and widen text inside mdframed

Tags: mdframed, bold

I am generating a report that spans multiple pages, and I'm using the `mdframed` package to display some data inside a box. I would like all the text inside the `mdframed` to appear in bold. Simply wrapping the section in `\textbf{}` isn't working. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\global\mdfdefinestyle{default}{%
  usetwoside=false,%
  linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,%
  innerleftmargin=10pt,innerrightmargin=0,%
  leftmargin=-120pt,rightmargin=-120pt,%
  everyline=true
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=default]
\begin{verbatim}
\textbf{

ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU WXY Z
123 456 789 123 456 789 123 456 7

}
\end{verbatim}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

which results in: [image]

Putting the `\textbf{}` outside the `\begin{verbatim}` results in an error. What am I doing wrong?

Also, as you can see, the text only occupies a very small fraction of the table. Is there a way to widen the text so that it occupies a bigger part of the table? It doesn't need to occupy the full table, but atleast half would be nice. To be clear, I'm not asking how to align in to the center, or make the table smaller, I would specifically like to widen the text. Thanks for the help.

Edit: I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162000/how-to-have-bold-font-in-mdframed-environment?rq=1) question, and it suggested I add `font=\bfseries` to `\mdfdefinestyle`, but I tried it and it didn't make a difference. It still looks the same. [image]

Comment: @Bernard, I tried it and it didn't work. A quick google search led me to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131180/bfseries-bolds-more-than-intended), and none of the methods suggested there work. The text still looks the same. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is an age old problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215482/how-do-i-get-texttt-with-bold-face-in-latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Verbatim` environment, from `fancyvrb`, and the optional argument of the environment. As there's very little difference bthe default to `inconsolata` to show it works:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\global\mdfdefinestyle{default}{%
  usetwoside=false,%
  linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,%
  innerleftmargin=10pt,innerrightmargin=0,%
  leftmargin=-120pt,rightmargin=-120pt,%
  everyline=true
}
\usepackage{zi4}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=default]
\bfseries
\begin{Verbatim}[fontseries = b]
ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU WXY Z
123 456 789 123 456 789 123 456 7
\end{Verbatim}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{verbatim}
ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU WXY Z
123 456 789 123 456 789 123 456 7
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]